# Python script to change emails subject on Outlook changes only the subject of a selected email

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, automation, outlook

So I've got a script to change emails' subjects in a specified folder:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from time import sleep

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
acc = outlook.Folders("mail@outlook.com")
eMailFolder = acc.folders("folder_name")
messages = eMailFolder.Items

def replaceSubjectLine(email:object):
        print("OLD SUBJECT:", email.Subject)
        email.Subject = "This is a test subject"
        email.Save
        print("NEW SUBJECT:", email.Subject)
        sleep(2)

for message in list(messages):
    replaceSubjectLine(message)
    messages = eMailFolder.Items
    message = messages.GetFirst()
```

The problem is that it ONLY changes the subject of a selected email in my Outlook application even if I refresh the whole inbox. If I select all by doing CTRL + A it still doesn't work or changes the subject of the email that is shown in the right panel to see the email's content. Why and how do I fix it? I save every modified subject in the function `replaceSubjectLine` so what is happening and why doesn't it work on all of the emails in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to get a new `Items` collection every time in the loop and get the first item every time:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from time import sleep

outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
acc = outlook.Folders("mail@outlook.com")
eMailFolder = acc.folders("folder_name")
messages = eMailFolder.Items

def replaceSubjectLine(email:object):
        print("OLD SUBJECT:", email.Subject)
        email.Subject = "This is a test subject"
        email.Save
        print("NEW SUBJECT:", email.Subject)
        sleep(2)

for message in messages:
    replaceSubjectLine(message)
```